# Custom ModelAdmin: allow admin class validation to ignore fields in a fieldset?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I am writing a little app to allow an [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/) share field in the django admin change list to allow the user share the object they are currently editing (as well as seeing the share count):

[image]

Taking a simple BlogEntry as an example, I have created a custom ModelAdmin:

```
class AddThisAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    addthis_config = {
        'title_field' : None,
        'description_field' : None, 
        'url_field' : None,
        'image_field' : None,
    }

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
        metaform = super(AddThisAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj:
            # Grab users config and find the fields they specified ...
            metaform.base_fields['add_this'] = AddThisField(self.add_this)
        return metaform
```

Which is inherited in the users BlogEntryAdmin like so:

```
class BlogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, AddThisAdmin):
    addthis_config = {
        'title_field' : 'blog_title',
        'description_field' : 'blurb',
    }
```

where the `addthis_config` allows the user to specify the fields in their BlogEntry object from where to pull the title/description/url and image used in AddThis. This all works really nicely until I decide to use a custom fieldset in the BlogEntryAdmin:

```
class BlogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, AddThisAdmin):
    addthis_config = {
        'title_field' : 'blog_title',
        'description_field' : 'blurb',
    }
    fieldsets = [{ ... }]
```

> 'BlogEntry.fieldsets[0](https://www.addthis.com/)['fields']' refers to field 'add_this' that is missing from the form.

I understand that this is happening because the django admin runs a validation on the fieldsets (django.contrib.admin.validation) on the BlogEntryAdmin class before it is actually instantiated (and my custom field is inserted).

**tldr** : Is there a way I can tell the `django.contrib.admin.validation` to ignore the field in the fieldset?

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason that you inherit from `ModelAdmin` and `AddThisAdmin` instead of only `AddThisAdmin`? Won't `BlogEntry.get_form()` resolve to the `ModelAdmin`'s `get_form`, not your custom one?

Comment: My comment above might be completely wrong. It's late, and I can get MRO wrong when I'm much more awake than now ;)

Comment: No you are right, there's no need for the multi inheritance I don't think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach is to provide base form like `AddThisAdminForm` which has the required field(s), and the make other ModelAdmin's forms inherit from that. It looks like you're trying to avoid that and auto insert the fields into whatever form is being used. If you insist on that approach, something like the following should work much better:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    ModelForm = super(AddThisAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    class AddThisForm(ModelForm):
        add_this = AddThisField(self.add_this)

    return AddThisForm
```

Comment: Yea, I'm want to set it up so that the extra field is automatically inserted after inheriting from the AddThisModelAdmin so it's as reusable as possible. The above seems to still cause the same error. From what I can tell, `django.admin.validator` is called before any ModelAdmin is instantiated and it uses some class methods to perform validation which means get_form isn't called until after this process? I'm not 100% sure though

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted as I ended up doing what you suggested in the first part of your answer: created a AddThisForm which adds a field and conditionally hides the whole row (using a widget with some javascript) if an object isn't saved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented, but you could use the `get_fieldsets` method to define your fieldsets. As an example, look at how Django changes the fieldsets in the [`UserAdmin`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py) when adding new users.

I've not tested this, but I believe it will avoid the `fieldset` validation.

Comment: I had noticed that but I'm trying to write it so that I can simply inherit from AddThisModelAdmin and not have to do anything else (for resue in the future). With this method (as I understand it?) I would need to overwrite the `get_fieldsets` method in every model admin I wanted to use the field (as well as inheriting AddThisModelAdmin)

Comment: You'll need to balance re-usability against the magic/ugliness required to achieve it. Monkey patch `validate`? Potentially a lot of repetition if you want to keep the rest of the `ModelAdmin` validation. Some metaclass magic on `AddThisAdmin` that deletes the `fieldset` attribute and adds a replacement `get_fieldsets` method? Tricky at first then even trickier when you try to handle a `ModelAdmin` that implements `get_fieldsets`. Good luck.

Comment: This is a good point. I might be overthinking the reusability aspect of the whole thing. It might be easier to supply an overwritten template with the javascript and provide the variables via the modeladmin change_view or something. Thanks for the help